# Are `Children` generally in the reversed order? Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, children, axes

I have a figure as shown here, with each color indicating the value of a third variable. I attempted to create a `colorbar` with the corresponding colors and values. For this purpose first I `get` the `Color` of the `'Children'` of the axes as follows:

```
curves = get(gca, 'Children');
mycolorset = cat(1, curves(:).Color);
```

Then I realized that the order of the colors (same as the order of the `Children`) is reversed compared to the order of plotting. So I had to apply `flipud` to the colors to make the correct colormap:

```
set(gcf, 'Colormap', flipud(mycolorset));
```

Interesting fact is that *Plot Browser* shows the curves in the correct order.

Now I want to know, is this a universal feature of all `Children` in Matlab to be reversed? Do you know a case that this becomes useful at all?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Children` of an `axes` are ordered such that the children near the beginning are displayed on top of children near the end of the list of children (if the [`SortMethod` is set to `'childorder'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_SortMethod) or if you have just a 2D plot).

If you're dynamically adding multiple 2D plots to an `axes`, the default behavior of MATLAB is to place new plot objects on top of old plot objects, therefore they need to be appended to the beginning of the `Children` list.

```
figure;
hold on
plot1 = plot(1:10, 'LineWidth', 10, 'DisplayName', 'plot1');
plot2 = plot(10:-1:1, 'LineWidth', 10, 'DisplayName', 'plot2');
legend([plot1, plot2])

get(gca, 'Children')

%  2x1 Line array:
%
%  Line    (plot2)
%  Line    (plot1)
```

[image]

If you want to alter which plot is displayed on top of which, you can modify the ordering of the `Children` or you can just use the handy [`uistack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html) command to do this for you.

```
set(gca, 'Children', flipud(get(gca, 'Children')))  % Or uistack(plot1, 'top')
get(gca, 'Children')

%  2x1 Line array:
%
%  Line    (plot1)
%  Line    (plot2)
```

[image]

This stacking behavior isn't just limited to plot objects in `axes`. You can alter the `Children` ordering on most UI elements (including `uipanels`, `figures`, etc.) to determine the visual stacking of the elements.